# Borrar jpg de goole drive con Python

Tags: python, imagen, google-drive

Tengo un codigo de python para borrar archivos jpg de una carpeta de google drive. Los archivos son pantallazos de movil. Lo curioso del tema es que los jpg que son pantallazos no me los deja borrar, pero otros archivos jpg si que me los deja borrar sin ningun problema. Desde google drive tampoco tengo problema en borrarlos manualmente. Evidentemente, las credenciales están bien, sino no podría borrar otros jpg y a priori el codigo tambien esta bien por el mismo motivo. No se si tiene algo que ver que sean pantallazos de movil. En cualquier caso, adjunto el codigo por si alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias.

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# Definir las credenciales de la cuenta de servicio imagenes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'C:/Users/elena/Documents/PYTHON/dividirimagenespython-a153c4364afe.json'
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Crear el objeto de servicio de Google Drive
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# ID de la carpeta que contiene los archivos a eliminar
folder_id = '1oR9U4l7efLInlkYMaFNKa4VEfaS9FV3y'

# Buscar los archivos en la carpeta con el nombre "666.jpg"
query = "name='666.jpg' and trashed=false and '{}' in parents".format(folder_id)
results = service.files().list(q=query, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

# Verificar si se encontraron archivos para eliminar
if not items:
   print('No se encontraron archivos para eliminar.')
else:
   print(f'Se encontraron {len(items)} archivos para eliminar.')
   for item in items:
       file_id = item['id']
       file_name = item['name']
       print(f'Eliminando archivo {file_name}...')
       print(service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute())

       try:
           service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
           print(f'Archivo {file_name} eliminado correctamente.')
       except HttpError as error:
           print(f'Error al eliminar archivo {file_name}: {error}')
```

Comment: No se nada de la api, pero dando palos de ciego: probaste si se trata de un tema de permisos, todas las imagenes de pantallasos se originan en el mismo lado o si de hecho se encuentran realmente en drive?

Comment: En principio no es problema de permisos, porque tengo otro código que obtiene esas imágenes que no me borra y las secciona creando nuevas jpg. Las nuevas imágenes seccionadas las borra sin ningún problema en la misma carpeta. Cualquier pantallazo o foto hecha con móvil tampoco lo borra. Me inclino más porque las imágenes que genera un móvil tenga alguna característica que influye en su borrado, pero no da problemas al borrar la imagen manualmente desde Google Drive,. Ya no se por donde tirar en algo que debería ser bastante sencillo. De todas formas, muchas gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Si que quiero añadir que el problema que me da al intentar borrar esos jpg es que no tengo suficientes permisos para eliminar esos archivos, pero realmente tienen los mismos permisos que los archivos jpg que si me deja borrar, tanto las carpetas donde se ubican como los archivos

Comment: Este es el error que me genera Eliminando archivo 666.jpg...
{'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '1aLf0JGfdyMTCguiTh0WeMU8rPNM8oKzs', 'name': '666.jpg', 'mimeType': 'image/jpeg'}
Error al eliminar archivo 666.jpg: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1aLf0JGfdyMTCguiTh0WeMU8rPNM8oKzs? returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "[{'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions'}]">

Comment: Bueno, el error dice que tu programa no tiene permisos. Quizá tu usuario si tiene permisos, pero no tu programa. Yo revisaría los permisos que tiene tu programa.

Comment: Puedes ser un poco mas explicito, es que soy bastante novato en esto. Te refieres a los permisos en python o en google drive. En cualquier caso, donde tendría que comprobar los permisos en python a priori tengo creadas las credenciales y el codigo accede a ellas, también el token y el id del canal de discord donde quiero alojar las imagenes. Me hace falta algo más? Y si es así donde tendria que modificar los permisos de python?

Comment: Soy mas novato que vos con la api de google. Me refiero a los permisos de Python, o de si tu programa tiene permisos para acceder a esos archivos. No digo tus permisos, si no los de tu programa.

Comment: En principio, hasta donde conozco, los permisos los concedes a Python con las credenciales creadas en la consola de Google. Si hubiera más permisos a conceder lo desconozco.